# There is speed/security difference Storing temporary Data in Files Vs Temporary table?

Tags: file, temporary

If I want to store a simple variable, I could do in a php file that will be included later, and, when not needed anymore, be deleted, or in a MySQL table with the MEMORY storage engine  which is better?(and fastest?)

1. Storing in a MySQL table with the MEMORY storage engine.
2. Storing in a "file.php" in some folder. (I create that file using php)

Comment: Have you run any performance tests?

Comment: nope, i dont know how to run those tests. i was expection someone would know. =/

Answer (score 0):

Storing info in memory will almost always be faster than writing to and reading from disk, often by orders of magnitude.  As ChrisF said, you should always test a supposed optimization, but in principal you can expect memory to be faster.

There will also be less overhead than storing the data in a table.  This can be good or bad - validating data types or maintaining uniqueness may be valuable to you, or it may be needless if your application is handling it.  If there's a lot of data, then the querying and indexing capabilities of MySQL may be helpful.

One note - if you do create a temp file, I wouldn't use the .php extension.  Depending on your host config, it may be readable to visitors by default.  If it's genuinely temporary data, use a .tmp extension, and ensure that the folder is not publicly accessible.